# How to stop flip timer at a specific number

Tags: javascript

I'm playing with a counter that won't stop. I'd like it to stop at a specific number.

```
// Initialize a new counter
var myCounter = new flipCounter('flip-counter', {
    value: 0, 
    inc: 1, 
    pace: 6, 
    auto: true
});
```

I'm was thinking it would be something along the lines of the following:

```
if (flipCounter.value > 10) {
    myCounter.stop();
}
```

If someone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Comment: what is flipCounter ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant a time counter. This is the one I'm using:
http://demo.cnanney.com/apple-counter-revisited/

Obviously the 'stop' button stops it, however, I'd like it to stop at a number that I designate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use    `incrementTo(num, time, pace)`

From [their](http://cnanney.com/journal/code/apple-style-counter-revisited/) docs:

> incrementTo(num, time, pace) *new* Increments to a given number either
>   by using the currently set pace and inc values, or by using a "smart"
>   increment technique that determines optimal values for you. To use the
>   simple technique, all you need to supply is the target number:
>   myCounter.incrementTo(12345); This will increment to 12,345 using the
>   current pace and inc values. To use the smart method, supply the time
>   in seconds you want the increment process to last, and a desired pace:
>   myCounter.incrementTo(12345, 10, 400); This will increment to 12,345
>   as well, but the increment process will take 10 seconds to complete.
>   The counter will determine the optimal values to use. In the example
>   I've set a desired pace of 400, which the counter will try and stay as
>   close to as possible when finding the optimal values. This method is
>   not chainable. num [int]: Number to increment to. time [int]
>   (optional): Duration, in seconds, the increment process should take.
>   When set, the counter will use a smart increment technique to optimize
>   the animation. pace [int] (optional): Desired pace for animation when
>   using the smart increment option. This number may increase as needed
>   for optimal timing.

Comment: Yes, that worked: myCounter.incrementTo(300, 5, 5);

Thank you.